# Is this sentence 100% correct by using the gerund？

Tags: word-choice

In this sentence, I would prefer to say *to remove* instead of the gerund *removing*.

> The only way to save its life was *removing* the infected leg.

I can't tell why but just strongly feel it's better to use "to remove". Is my doubt worth supporting?

Comment: *...was removing* gives me a flair of the leg being removed. *to remove* merely gives me an idea (though very true) to remove the leg.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps *to remove* sounds better to you because the preposition helps the sentence flow better. If so, you could consider:

> The only way to save its life was by removing the infected leg.

Otherwise, you could rearrange the sentence, like this:

> Removing the infected leg was the only way to save its life.

I find that a many sentences starting out with an expression like:

> The one thing we had to do was...
>   The best solution was...

end up sounding a little awkward in the middle. Oftentimes, it reads better if we say:

> Moving forward was the one thing we had to do.
>   Rearranging the sentence was the best solution.

Comment: In this sentence, is it better to suggest a possible future solution by using an inffinitive? "Was to remove the infected leg" sounds more of something being about to happen or being about to be chosen,but hasn't happen or been chosen yet.

Comment: @denny - No. If the leg hasn't been amputated yet, we'd say: "The only way to save its life **is** by removing the infected leg" (or, "Removing the infected leg **is** the only way to save its life").